# Use NiFi to write into AWS S3 Bucket with MFA enabled

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-s3, apache-nifi, hortonworks-data-platform

Is it possible to use the NiFi processor PutS3Object to write data into a S3 Bucket, while MFA is active?

And if not, what would be an alternative considering writing data to S3 from hive/HDFS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of version 1.8.0, I do not believe this is supported by the Apache NiFi `*S3Object` processors (or the [`AWSCredentialsProviderControllerService`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-aws-nar/1.8.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.aws.credentials.provider.service.AWSCredentialsProviderControllerService/index.html)). I recommend opening a feature request ticket on the [Jira site](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:summary-panel). You may be able to accomplish this immediately by using one of the following options:

- Use `ExecuteStreamCommand` or `ExecuteProcess` to call a terminal command or shell script using the [AWS S3 CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/)
- Use `ExecuteScript` to run a custom Python (/Ruby/Groovy/etc.) script which uses the AWS S3 SDK directly ([example code](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_mfa_sample-code.html))
- Write a custom processor which uses the [AWS S3 SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/) directly